# Whats the difference between white and yellow corn meal. and all cornmeal or half flour half cornmeal

Tags: baking, substitutions, flour, corn

I usually make cornbread with white corn meal and no sugar. I like the no sugar part, but I want to experiment with the batter a bit. What are the following changes supposed to achieve:

- Yellow corn meal as opposed to white
- Half flour in the mix.

My normal corn meal recipe is [this](http://www.originalsforyou.com/southernrecipes.html)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you're comparing two very different recipes: Northern cornbread (yellow meal, equal parts flour, a tablespoon or so of sugar) and Southern cornbread (white meal, no or little flour, no sugar).  There's no real point in trying to mix and match or interpolate between the recipes, any more than than it would make sense to make something halfway between cioppino and bouillabaisse, since they are both just fish stew.

Comment: I think you've got Southern and Northern styles crossed-up there. Southern cornbread is not sweet--that's Yankee style.

Comment: Doh, you're right.  Editing

Answer (score 1):

I've never found a difference between yellow and white corn meal, when it comes to cooking.

Since it doesn't look like your recipe calls for wheat flour, i'd stay away from the 50/50 mix. Self rising cornmeal isn't the same as cornmeal MIX. Think about the properties of wheat flour verses cornmeal (has gluten -- so may rise better, become chewy, etc). This will give you an idea of what it might do to your recipe.

Answer (score 1):

The color is simply the color of corn used - white or yellow.

I use a self-rising cornmeal mix which contains a percentage (not sure but more cornmeal than flour) of each. 50% flour will make your cornbread more like cake. 100% cornmeal will be the opposite and much drier. It all depends on the taste and texture you are trying to achieve. I am southern and do not do sugar in any of my corn products...:) I think the mix I use is about 25% flour, but I could be way off as I have no clue.  Both are cheap so experiment until you find your perfect balance....

Comment: Welcome! It’s perfectly ok to post answers to “old” posts. This is not a discussion forum where nobody cares about old threads, but the Stack Exchange network explicitly aims to create a knowledge base where Q/As are useful now and in the future. If you want to learn more, there’s the [tour] and the [help].